# Using a component to display array rows

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Newbie hacking my way through. I'm trying to pull rows from an array and display them in a screen. I have the array populated and the snippet of code below works:

```
return (
        buildings.map((building) => {
          return <div className="col-md-9"> 
             {building.name}
```

But when I try to use a component in the statement I get an error. This doesn't work:

```
return (
        buildings.map((building) => {
          return <div className="col-md-9"> 
             <Building building={building.name}/>
```

The Building component is here:

```
import React from 'react'

function Building({building}) {
  return (
    <div className="row">
      <h1>{building.name}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Building
```

The error I get is here:

> src/screens/Homescreen.js   Line 34:15:  'Building' is not defined
> react/jsx-no-undef

I can provide more details if necessary. I think I'm missing something obvious but I'm stuck at the moment so any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to import the Building component in your  src/screens/Homescreen.js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check to see if you are importing `Building` component.
secondly, `<Building building={building.name}/>` you are passing down the name attribute of building and then in the Building component, trying to access that name attribute. This should be changed to `<Building building={building}/>`. Fix these to see if the problem continues to exist.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I was dealing with 2 problems. First I didn't import the component, and second I didn't realize the {building.name} should be {building}. Once I fixed both of those it is working as expected at this point!